# Loop through different ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have multiple Listbox named Box0, Box1, Box2 etc.
In each of the Box I want to add the corresponding element of an array, but don't know how to call each of them.
Should be something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Box[i].Items.Add(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: What are `Box` and `array`? Is `array` a jagged array? Or do you have an array of ListBox Controls and a single array of values? Or an array ListBox Controls and a jagged array of values? You should show how you declare the objects you're working with.

Comment: `((ListBox)this.Controls[$"Box{i}"]).DataSource = array.ToArray();` should do the trick. `this.Controls.OfType<ListBox>().ToList().ForEach(lb => lb.DataSource = array.ToArray());` also should do the trick. (If their parent is different, instead of this, you can use their parent.) You can also find controls by name, using `Find` method of the `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best create a `List<ListBox>` boxes, add all your `listboxes` to it and then loop over the boxes like so: `foreach (ListBox lb in boxes){..}` or use a normal `for` loop if you need the indices: `for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Count; i++) ){..}`

Source: Comment by Taw